# Neural network model not learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried to model a NN using softmax regression. 
After 999 iterations, I got error of about 0.02% for per data point, which i thought was good. But when I visualize the model on tensorboard, my cost function did not reach towards 0 instead I got something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k35I.png)

And for weights and bias histogram [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cplqP.png)

I am a beginner and I can't seem to understand the mistake. May be I am using a wrong method to define cost?

Here is my full code for reference.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

lorange= 1
hirange= 10
amplitude= np.random.uniform(-10,10)
t= 10
random.seed()
tau=np.random.uniform(lorange,hirange)


x_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (10,))
y_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (10,))

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10,10], stddev= .1))
b = tf.Variable(.1)

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(x_node,[1,10]), W) + b)

##ADD SUMMARY

W_hist = tf.histogram_summary("weights", W)
b_hist = tf.histogram_summary("biases", b)
y_hist = tf.histogram_summary("y", y)

# Cost function sum((y_-y)**2)
with tf.name_scope("cost") as scope:
   cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_node-y))
   cost_sum = tf.scalar_summary("cost", cost)

# Training using Gradient Descent to minimize cost
with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Merge all the summaries and write them out to logfile
merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/mnist_logs_4", sess.graph_def)
error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y - y_node))


init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

steps = 1000

for i in range(steps):
    xs = np.arange(t)
    ys = amplitude * np.exp(-xs / tau)

    feed = {x_node: xs, y_node: ys}
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed)
    print("After %d iteration:" % i)
    print("W: %s" % sess.run(W))
    print("b: %s" % sess.run(b))
    print('Total Error: ', error.eval(feed_dict={x_node: xs, y_node:ys}))
    # Record summary data, and the accuracy every 10 steps
    if i % 10 == 0:
      result = sess.run(merged, feed_dict=feed)
      writer.add_summary(result, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same plot like you a couple of times.

That happened mostly when I was running tensorboard on multiple log-files. That is, the logdir I gave to TensorBoard contained multiple log-files. Try to run TensorBoard on one single log-file and let me know what happens

Comment: I created a new log-file and tried. this is what i got- http://imgur.com/a/NFXul 
But the cost is still not approaching zero, any idea why? and also weights and bias are confusing

in my script i wrote- 
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/tensorflow/logdir_1", sess.graph_def)

and from trminal- 
                 tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow/logdir_1